# Assembly safes and keys- why it won't work?

Tags: debugging, assembly, reverse-engineering, x86-16, corewars

So we have like this safes challenge in assembly, you need to create safes and keys that will break them and end the infinite loop.
Here's an example for a safe:

```
loopy:
mov ax, [1900]
cmp ax,1234
jne loopy
```

and a key:

```
loopy2:
mov ax, 1234
mov [1900],ax
jmp loopy2
```

So I have a safe and a key, and I don't understand why it doesn't work:

here's my safe:

```
org 100h
mySafe:  
mov dx,5
mov ax, [5768h] 
mov bx,7 
mov word [180h],2
mul word [180h]
mov [180h],bx
push ax
dec bx
mov cx,dx
mov ax,dx
loopy1:
add bx,ax
loop loopy1
dec bx
pop ax
add ax,bx
mul word [180h]
cmp ax,350
jne mySafe
```

And here's my key:

```
org 100h
loopy:
mov word [5768h],10
jmp loopy


ret
```

The right answer to break the loop should be 10 and it works when I put in on the safe, somehow with the key it doesn't work and I can't figure out why..
(the "word" is needed for nasm)

Comment: Your "key" never exits.  Is that not a problem?   It should only need to run once for the "safe" loop to be unlocked forever.  Unless you're running multiple processes under a multi-tasking OS, infinite loops are bad.

Comment: Your "safe" is too complex for me to simulate in my head.  When you single-step it in a debugger, do you see it loading `10` from `[5768h]`?   If so, then does it not eventually end up with `ax == 350`?   "Doesn't work" isn't detailed enough for a [mcve].

Comment: My key is supposed to run in an infinite loop. It runs in a program of  codeguru and the key is supposed to win, which means it supposed to break the infinite loop of the safe. however, it always ends up being a tie. means the key doesn't do it's job..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in `dx` used as the counter for the `loop` instruction comes from the first `mul` instruction.

This multiplication is just doubling the key, so `dx` is either 0 or 1 (an easy way to see this is to think of the multiplication as a left shift by one or by remembering that the sum of two n-bit numbers has at most *n+1* bits)

---

If `dx` is zero, the whole `loopy1` block does nothing (as `dx` also sets `ax`) and the value in `ax` at the end of the safe is 7*(5 +2k) where *k* is the key (see the commented code below).

It is then easy to see that 350 = 7*(5+2k) => 2k = 45 has no solution. Therefore no key for which `dx` is zero can unlock the safe.
A key has `dx` 0 iif its value is less than 32768 (again, this is easy to see when thinking of the multiplication as a left shift by one).

Corollary: 10 cannot be a solution.

```
safe:
  mov dx,5
  mov ax, [k]               ;ax = k (key)
  mov bx,7 
  mov word [aux],2    
  mul word [aux]            ;dx = 0 ax = 2k
  mov [aux],bx              ;aux = 7
  push ax                   ;ax = 2k
  dec bx                    ;bx = 6 
  dec bx                    ;bx =    5
  pop ax                    ;ax = 2k
  add ax,bx                 ;ax = 5 + 2k
  mul word [aux]            ;ax = 7*(5 +2k)

  cmp ax,350
  ret
```

---

If there is a key that unlocks the safe then it must be greater or equal to 32768 so that `dx` is 1 after the first multiplication.
With this condition, the value in `ax` at the end of the safe can be written as 7*(6 + (2k & 0xffff)) => k & 0x7fff = 22.
Adding the condition stated at the very beginning of this section, **the final value for *k* is 32768 + 22 = 32790 or 0x8016 in hex**.
I've leaped quite a few logical steps in manipulating the equation and forming the result but, again, thinking of `2k` as a shift may help visualize them.

Corollary: Due to the algebraic structure involved, this is the only solution.

```
safe:
  mov dx,5
  mov ax, [k]           ;ax = k
  mov bx,7 
  mov word [aux],2    
  mul word [aux]            ;dx:ax = 2k
  mov [aux],bx              ;[aux] = 7
  push ax                   ;dx = 1 ax = 2k & 0xffff
  dec bx                    ;bx = 6 
  mov cx,dx                 ;cx = 1
  mov ax,dx                 ;ax = 1
loopy1:
  add bx,ax                 ;bx = 6 + 1
  dec cx
jnz loopy1
  dec bx                    ;bx = 6 
  pop ax                    ;ax = 2k & 0xffff
  add ax,bx                 ;ax = 6 + (2k & 0xffff)
  mul word [aux]            ;ax = 7*(6 + (2k & 0xffff))

  cmp ax,350
  ret
```

---

Considering that you have a `mov dx, 5` before the first multiplication, **did you (or the author of the safe) forget that `mul` affects `dx`**?
If you wrap the first `mul` in `push dx / pop dx` (or just move `mov dx, 5` after it), you would get, at the end of the safe, a value in `ax` equals to 7*(30 +2k) which implies *k = 10* indeed.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! you have no idea how much I apperciate it!!